# Update sql statement in servlet not in servlet

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I am trying to allow the user to change the password if he enters the right username. The username is drawn from the database and compared to the username the user enter in a form. My problem is after the validation is done the UPDATE statement is not producing any result. Can someone help me out please?

```
   String un = request.getParameter("username");
    String psw = request.getParameter("password");
    String cPsw = request.getParameter("cpassword");
    Connection con = ConnectionHelper.getConnection();

    try {
        ResultSet rs = userList(con);
        if (rs.next()) {

            String n = rs.getString("username");

            if (n.equals(un)) {
                out.print("Password match");
                String updateQuery = "UPDATE RegisteredUserInfo SET password ='"
                        + cPsw + "'WHERE username ='" + un + "'";

                PreparedStatement ps1 = con.prepareStatement(updateQuery);
                ps1.executeQuery();

                ServletContext context = getServletContext();
                RequestDispatcher rd = context
                        .getRequestDispatcher("/Welcome.jsp");
                rd.forward(request, response);
            }
        }

    } catch (SQLException sx) {
        out.println();
    }
}

public ResultSet userList(Connection con) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement ps;
    ResultSet rs;
    String matchingUname = "SELECT username FROM RegisteredUserInfo";
    ps = con.prepareStatement(matchingUname);
    rs = ps.executeQuery();
    return rs;`
```

Comment: add space between ' and WHERE  .. it might work

Comment: Thanks executeUpdate() worked perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `ps1.execute();` or `ps1.executeUpdate()` instead of `ps1.executeQuery();`

Call `con.commit();` to commit the changes and **Don't** forget to close the resources in the end.

---

Check the *return type* of below methods to make sure that data is inserted properly.

#### ResultSet executeQuery()

Executes the SQL query in this PreparedStatement object and returns the ResultSet object generated by the query.

#### int executeUpdate()

Executes the SQL statement in this PreparedStatement object, which must be an SQL INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statement; or an SQL statement that returns nothing, such as a DDL statement.

Ream more about [Difference between execute, executeQuery, executeUpdate](http://www.coderanch.com/t/301594/JDBC/databases/Difference-execute-executeQuery-executeUpdate)

---

### Points to Remember

- Use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead of using single quoted query string that may cause issue. Find a sample on [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)
- **Don't** forget to close the resources such as connection, result set and statement.
- Use **finally** block to handle it or Read more about [Java7 -The try-with-resources Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)
- **Don't** simply eat the exception in catch block. Do proper handling of the exception. You can try with `e.printStackTrace()` while development.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `executeUpdate()` for SQL UPDATE (or INSERT/DELETE).

```
            String updateQuery = "UPDATE RegisteredUserInfo SET password = ?"
                    + " WHERE username = ?";

            PreparedStatement ps1 = con.prepareStatement(updateQuery);
            ps1.setString(1, cPsw);
            ps1.setString(2, un);
            ps1.executeUpdate();
```

Also use the PreparedStatement as above. Look for SQL Injection, also escapes `'`.